# Is there any possibility to change the default read only property of splitcontainer1.panel2 (VB)?

Tags: vb.net

I need to set the size of splitcontainer1.panel2 but Visual Studio give me an error because the panel2 is read only.
Is there any method for setting the size of the panel ? 
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets the width of `Panel2` to `20px`:

```
Dim width As Integer = 20

Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2MinSize = 0
Me.SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance = (Me.SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle.Right - Me.SplitContainer1.SplitterWidth - width)
```

Comment: Good suggestion , but with that code I see however a small part of Panel2

Comment: @MattiaPierdicca I've edited the answer to include the `SplitterWidth`. Please confirm that you've tested this edit. If yes, what's the difference of `width` - `.Panel2.Width`?

Comment: Great job ! With this edit, I can get an acceptable layout.
I can always see a part of the second panel, but this time is almost imperceptible. P.S : I replace "width" with "0"

Comment: @MattiaPierdicca Nice! BUT, why did you replace the, and I love this part, "width" with "0"? If you want do hide a panel you could simply do `Me.SplitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = True` or `Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = True`.

Comment: I probably confused ; with the last answer I can  completely hide the panel 2 . Thank you very much for your help, unfortunately I learned to program recently and I'm still a noob in many things :)